# How to use make unique to create a pointer to a base class instead of wrapping new in a unique pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

Say there are two classes, Base which contains certain parameters and D which contains more parameters. I need to make a variable with Base type then pass there type D which inherits from base.

```
class Base {
protected:
  Base(const String& sFileName,
                    const String& filetype);
};


class D : public Base
{
public:
    D(const String& sFileName,
                    const String& filetype, boost::shared_ptr<custom_type> requester)
};


int main()
{
 //this works
 return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new D(sFileName, filetype, requester));
 //this does not
 return std::make_unique<Base>(sFileName, filetype, requester);

 
}
```

does anyone know why the first return works but the second does not?
It throws an error saying error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type Base

I tried converting the unique pointer with a New object into a make_unique and it threw errors

Comment: `std::make_unique<Base>(sFileName, filetype, requester)` does `std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Base(sFileName, filetype, requester))`. You need `std::make_unique<D>(sFileName, filetype, requester)`

Comment: What if the return type needs to be unique_ptr<Base>

Comment: it'll convert automatically (assuming the pointer is a temporary/l-value)

Comment: Thank you, that was it, if you want to post that as an answer for posterity, I can upvote and accept it